# Configure Jira Customer Portal

Tags: jira, admin

Take a look at the filter being applied here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSDCLOUD-11593?filter=98705

Is it possible to replicate what Atlassian has done here? Can tickets in an org be viewable from a filter like they have done here?  Where essentially a customer can view all tickets without even logging in to Jira? The customizations I have seen for the Customer portal are quite limited and like the visibility on their board. From what I have seen, the Jira portal's filterability is much more limited than is being used here.